# Find weighted mean with multiple columns?

Tags: r, statistics

This is the formula:

.  ×  + .  ×  + .  ×

i want to find the weighted mean from 3 columns that represent the **R**,**F** and **M**

I tried this:

```
vvv$rfm_score=weighted.mean(x=c(vvv$rank_recency, vvv$rank_freq, vvv$rank_monetary_v)
              ,w=c(.2,.3,.5))
```

but the column it gives is the same for all the rows?

To clarify, each column has a number from 1 to 5.Later the weighted mean is calculated as it shows in the formula using every time one of the columns as required.

The problem is definitely in the way i used the `weighted.mean` function but after trying different ways and looking up to the help page i could find the correct approach.

Comment: The weights argument is `w`, not `y`.

Comment: Maybe `apply(vvv, 1, weighted.mean, w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))`.

Comment: @ekstroem ; assuming there is no missing

Comment: @ekstroem Probably the matrix version is correct but can you make the `apply` version work on the example because it returns: `'x' and 'w' must have the same length`

Comment: How about `apply(vvv[c("rank_recency", "rank_freq", "rank_monetary_v")], 1, weighted.mean, w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))` ?

Comment: sapply doesn't have a margin parameter you mean apply. Anyway with apply it works.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `rowwise` and `do` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(200)

# Make some data

vvv <-  matrix(sample(1:5,replace = TRUE,18),ncol = 3) %>% as.data.frame()

names(vvv) <- c("rank_recency","rank_freq","rank_monetary_v")  

head(vvv)
# rank_recency rank_freq rank_monetary_v
#            3         4               1
#            3         1               4
#            3         3               2
#            4         2               2
#            4         3               3
#            5         4               1

vvv$rfm_score <-   vvv %>% 
  rowwise() %>% # compute for each row
  do(data.frame(
            rfm_score=weighted.mean(
                          x=c(.$rank_recency,.$rank_freq,.$rank_monetary_v),
                          w=c(.2,.3,.5)
                      )
               )
     ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% # undo row groups
  use_series("rfm_score") # extract the weighted means

head(vvv)
# rank_recency rank_freq rank_monetary_v rfm_score
#            3         4               1       2.3
#            3         1               4       2.9
#            3         3               2       2.5
#            4         2               2       2.4
#            4         3               3       3.2
#            5         4               1       2.7
```

Using `rowwise` and `do`, you can pass `weighted.mean` the values as a three element vector for each row.